# Join SQL Table where join on column has user submitted entries

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables together. 1 table is Users and their responses and the 2nd table is Answer ID that corresponds to different options that the User can select.

In Table 2, there are some user entered entries.

In table 1,  any user entered value is Answer ID = 1. Other than the Answer ID =1, the response id and the answer id will match.

How do I join the two tables together?

I joined on the identifier but as there are multiple of each one, it creates duplicates.

**Snippet 1**:

```
Select *
from Table1
Join Table2 on Table1.identifier = Table2.identifier
```

Otherwise, **Snippet 2**:

```
select *
from Table1
Join Table2 on (Table1.identifier = Table2.identifier AND 
table2.response_id = table1.answer_id)
```

This fails because Response_id is var and answer id is INT.

When I do an AND condition for the join, it fails because user entries like 91.6 and then the answer id = 1.

With this snippet I get nothing because

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '91.6' to data type int.

For example, I want the table join to skip the matching when answer id = 1 (because answer_id=1=user entered) and match everything else.

**Table 1**

```
Identifier  Answer_iD   Text
-------------------------------------
     1          2       Male
     1          3       Female
     2          1       User Entered
     3          2       Answer1
     3          3       Answer2
     3          4       Answer3
```

**Table2**

```
User Identifier Response_id
---------------------------
Andy       1       2
Andy       2       91.6
Andy       3       2
```

I want this output:

```
User Identifier  Response_id  Answer_Id Text
--------------------------------------------
Andy     1          2            2       Male
Andy     2          91.6         1      User entered
Andy     3          2            2        Answer1
```

Right now with my SQL snippet 1  I get

```
User   Identifier  Response_id   Answer_Id   Text
--------------------------------------------
Andy     1              2        2           Male
Andy     1              2        3          Female
```

I don't have access to edit any of the tables and right I basically look up each identifier and answer_id in Table 1 manually to see what it stands for in the table. There's a 100 of identifiers for each person so it gets pretty tiring quick.

Any workarounds welcome.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please edit it an post the structure of the involved tables (as `CREATE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and the desired result with that sample data. Also include the query you already have and tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: A small example would help a lot.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have primary keys and foreign keys set up correctly. But as @stickybit says. supply the table definitions and it will be much clearer.

Comment: I don't have  access to edit tables. SSMS. Added some examples, but it's super hard to read because I can't make tables in stackoverflow.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Infact, the sample table shared by you doesn't match the description you are providing on top..kindly ask in a clear and better way

Comment: All your conversion errors are because you a joining on the wrong columns. Not even sure what the column “identifier” is. Primary key to user perhaps? Also looks wrong in your second table that you have responseid which would normally be a integer but then have 91.6 in there. Really need to see the tables. I could write a query that gives your desired result for the small sample but I suspect there is more too it than that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is this. Don’t understand what you want, but...

```
Select user, t2.identifier, t2.response_id, isnull(t1.answerid,t3.answerid)
From table2 t2
Left join table1 t1 on t1.identifier=t2.identifer and t1.answerid=t2.responseid
Left join table1 t3 on t3.identifer= t2.identifier and t3.answerid=1
```

Comment: Sorry what does t3 stand for? I have 2 tables to work with.

Comment: t3 is an alias for table 1. See the last join. It finds the entry where answerid=1.